# Are there any guides for design MetroUI-like interfaces for desktop apps like Zune or Metrotwit?

Tags: microsoft-metro

Of course, there is the [UX Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), but it, obviously, miss tips for the window header design and behavior.

I suppose MS is not interested in Metro apps on classic desktop, but may be some one else (hello, Metrotwit team ;) ) wrote something interesting?

Comment: Hello! 
- designer of MetroTwit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the documentation of the Windows 8 Metro apps that is slowly appearing.

When looking at Zune etc. they decided to get rid of the standard chrome/borders and implemented their own.

The problem is that the desktop still requires a minimize/maximize, title while these do not exist on Metro.

[My advise copy the ideas from Zune and others](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/06/16/i-want-my-app-to-look-like-the-zune-client.aspx). I do not expect any official guidance on this soon.

Answer (score 1):

Metro is also for Windows 8. Take a look at

- [8 traits of great Metro style apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004)
- [Designing Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465427.aspx)